# Where does my app data save on Android?

Tags: android

I'm running my android application through Eclipse on Toshiba tablet ( Which runs Android Gingerbread ). I'm saving some files though the application. Where can i find these files by browsing through the tablet. Because the file explorer on Eclipse do not show any files on tablet.

Comment: I assume that you are saving files in application data folder? If that is the case you need to export them to sd-card as data folder cannot be accessed by normal means (except if your tablet is rooted). Can you post a code that you use to save files/data?

Comment: Do you know any way to delete all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data can be deleted from the Settings -> Application -> Manage Applications -> Your Application -> Clear Data.

But to Save files/data you need 'adb push /data/data/complete_package_path/file_name destination'
For SD Card the destination is /mnt/sdcard/file_name.

Comment: i save my app data to "/data/data/complete_package_path/file_name" destination. this way my app data will be deleted after app uninstall?

Comment: Yes, whenever the application is uninstalled, its all data will be deleted by system, but if it replaced, data will be preserved (database scenario is different).